# wordfinder program in python

Tags: python

I am really new to programming. I was trying to write a code that takes a word, changes its character order, and checks if the new form is in the list. for example, the word "spam" is changed to `pams`, `amsp` and `mspa`. 
code is like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
mylist = open("D:/python/wordfinder/wordlist.txt").read().splitlines()
for item in mylist:
    x = []
    for i in range((len(item)-1)):
        x.append(i) 
        x[i] = item[i+1:] + item[i-i:i+1:]
        if x[i] in mylist: 
            print(x[i], file = open("output.txt", "a"))
```

It works fine with my sample list with 10 words. However my actual list has got over a million words in it. I ran the script an hour ago, should I stop it and change the code? what is a better way for my use case?

apologies if duplicate.

EDIT: It took 37 hours to search through a 1,337,898-item list and output a 10,882-item list.

Comment: Your code is ridiculously inefficient because you open the same output file at each iteration. The second inefficiency is looking up  value in a list `if x[i] in mylist` (linear search time!).

Comment: Other problems: List x is appending integers at first, then assigning strings, then being used to search for a string in mylist. Also, the time complexity of searching a list scales with the size of the list , so it is not the best choice of data structure for this problem. Have you covered data structures and time complexity in your study of Python yet? It would be needed for this type of problem.

Comment: haven't really, i'm still dealing with the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code takes quite a bit of time because of the numerous loops it runs through, and the fact that it opens a file each time it passes through the loop. Let's try to simplify the code here.

Let `word_list` be the list of words you would like to pass to the program, and `test_list` the list you want to test the newly formed words against.

The following code will print each word in `word_list` that has a new form in `test_list`, and print each of those words.

```
def word_mix(word):
    return [word[i:]+word[:i] for i in range(1,len(word))]
my_list = [set(word_mix(i)).intersection(test_list) for i in word_list]
for i in range(0,len(word_list)):
    if bool(my_list(i)):
        print(word_list[i]+': '+','.join(my_list[i]))
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot! i'll try it now. what if the wordlist and testlist is the same, because they are in my case? i don't have a separate testlist.